# MySQL subquery deadlock (kind of)

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, subquery, deadlock

I'm experiencing a problem when running this query:

```
select * from logs l
where l.id in(select max(id) 
from logs
group by usuario_id);
```

On this structure:

```
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| usuario_id      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| projeto_id      | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                |
| title           | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I've tried running this query on 3 different servers:

```
mysql> show variables like "%version%";
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.40                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Which is my personal computer, and this other 2:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.40                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

hosted on digitalocean and amazon.

On those systems, the mysql process keeps running at 100% when this query is sent and it stops only when the query is manually stopped...

The curious fact is that this query runs without any problems on windows (with wampp mysql)

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.12                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.12-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Is that an issue with the MySQL version or is this an issue with the OS?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a bunch of data in ubuntu sql databases, how many rows do you have in each database table? If you are looking for the most recent logs.id for each usuario_id, it should dramatically reduce query time to run this and then iterate through the usuario_ids and only get the title column when needed. varchar(500) is a lot of data.

```
select l.id,l.usuario_id from logs l
where l.id in(select max(id) 
from logs
group by usuario_id);
```

Comment: Hello...

I've 350971 records on all those databases (I've done mysql dump)... The query on the windows wampp returns the result with 0.650 ms...

Comment: Did you try to run my query and how long did it take to run? Also do you know if there are any indexes on either the ubuntu or windows database tables?

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, it is possible to rewrite the query to remove the subquery:

```
   SELECT l.*
     FROM logs l
LEFT JOIN logs lo
       ON lo.id > l.id
      AND lo.usuario_id = l.usuario_id
    WHERE lo.id IS NULL
```

This would at least help you in your steps to isolate the cause of the problem.

The other (obvious) step is to run the original query on the same data in Windows with MySQL v5.5.40